# Torguard VPN Ubuntu

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm having a weird issue. So I used torguard VPN for the first time, and when I was done, I shut down my computer. The next day I couldn't access the web at all unless I used the VPN. How do I fix this and why did it happen? I can now only use the internet when I'm connected to the VPN.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the TorGuard GUI, then click **More Settings** then check the **Block Outside DNS** box.

[image: 1]

After you disconnect, if it asks if you want to recover the original DNS click **Yes**.

Comment: I suggest that you get screenshots from Ubuntu rather than Windows.

Comment: @AndroidDev Will do once I have access to my machine with Ubuntu on it later. Also, you really like editing my answers :)

Comment: Nothing against you personally :) Just noticed you were new and I was checking out your profile :)

Comment: @AndroidDev Yeah, I'm trying. Thanks for checking out some little things that I got wrong, though. I appreciate it.

Comment: Since you're new, look at the revisions here, and notice I how fixed the code blocks to look a lot nicer: http://askubuntu.com/posts/835264/revisions

Comment: I don't have that option. My network tab on torguard is missing the checkbox options you have. I just have "prevent ivp6 leak (checked), Prevent DNS leak (checked), Manage Interface State (unchecked)

Comment: @AndroidDev Owen is new (member for 13 days) but is #4 in October points so far (1,374). Pretty impressive.